# Draw 3d image in runtime

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I interested, how can i draw 3d image in runtime using PHP,JS. (or what other programming language suggested for this..)

Specfically: I have a database-table with two filed. user and candle. For example Michael,100 means that Michael has 100 candle.

If i have a 10x10 candle image how can i use this image to draw a "3d candle image", something like [this](http://www.google.hu/imgres?imgurl=http://www.3dmodelfree.com/imguploads/Image/0911/zp/xz/3d/mx/0606/4.jpg&imgrefurl=http://www.3dmodelfree.com/models//27797-0.htm&usg=__HawS24vMNTwJwMmR7IM_bMifraM=&h=210&w=350&sz=53&hl=hu&start=285&sig2=1sDmwi2V7PjEWGVcae9oTw&zoom=1&tbnid=HKnXUazXp0TBaM%3a&tbnh=100&tbnw=166&ei=_lPpTKnwNdKBswb_jtGQCQ&prev=/images%3Fq%3D3d%2Bcandle%26hl%3Dhu%26biw%3D1568%26bih%3D725%26gbv%3D2%26tbs%3Disch:10%2C4881&itbs=1&iact=hc&vpx=805&vpy=501&dur=324&hovh=149&hovw=249&tx=145&ty=144&oei=zlPpTJXkOsz54AbekZj6Ag&esq=12&page=9&ndsp=37&ved=1t:429,r:33,s:285&biw=1568&bih=725)

So i have for exapmle a 300x300 DIV and i would like to fill in with the candle.png in 3d style. If the user have 3 candle in the database, then fill in with 3 candle randomly, if user have 30 then fill in with 30 candles..

Please help me how can i start this?

Comment: Can you please show a real world example to clarify further? If you want to do Raytracing in PHP, you can stop right away - but you might be able to invoke a 3rd party renderer (is POVRay still around?). Simple 2D copying operations might be possible out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

Rendering 3d graphics, while possible, is not really what php and javascript are created for.

If you are looking for a method of outputting pre-rendered images of candles to your page, then this is very easy with these languages, however I think you need to make your question more specific for a useful answer.

Comment: You don't know that. If he wants to copy a few sprites to create a 3D effect, it may be well within range.

Comment: Copying sprites is not the same as rendering 3d graphics.

Comment: you don't know whether he really wants to render 3D graphics. This question needs a lot of clarification

Comment: ok..im sorry..i dont really want to render 3d graph. I just want to show the candles as the linked image. The final image is depend the value in the database.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run arbitrary code on your server, I recommend creating a program using something like http://liballeg.org/ that runs with CGI and querying it from within javascript. I think you are looking for what is called an affine transformation; look it up; I believe that allegro supports them.

Comment: Specifically, you want the apply_matrix() function. Randomize the appropriate cells of a 3x3 transformation matrix for each candle then apply the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

How to approach this depends on how you want it displayed to the user, for example, if the user should be able to rotate the image then it would need to be done close to the user, ie on the browser.

If it is just a static bitmap is the final outcome then doing it on the server may be best, for performance.

Either way, it is a great deal of math involved, but I will assume you know the mathematics.

In order to do it in PHP you can use `gdlib` to save the image, and look for any examples in `C` on doing raytracing. It will be slow, and will be a performance hit on your webserver, but there are solutions to that.

If you want to do it in javascript, then your best bet would be to use the 3D canvas (https://wiki.mozilla.org/Canvas:3D), but this has very limited browser support at the moment, but it does give you access to an openGL API.